# When's the best time to ask questions?

Tags: discussion

Is there a specific time of day (please specify timezone you're in to convert from) when the site is most active? Or is there a good time relative to that (directly before, etc) to ask?

I will often find that I want more answers - I don't even care about views, but I want a variety of approaches without needing to set a bounty.

When do you normally ask your questions?
Does time even make a difference?

Comment: If you want more attention to your post in not-cheating kinds of ways, you can try things like breaking up posts into a series of linked questions, and answering it yourself after a day or two of idleness.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to get a couple Data Explorer queries from [Question and answer activity on StackExchange: Interactive and customized edition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213603/274942) on Meta Stack Exchange. I chose the query [Best time to ask questions on StackExchange: Get answer faster](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/155028/best-time-to-ask-questions-on-stackexchange-get-answer-faster), rather than [Best time to ask questions on StackExchange: More likely to get an answer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/155865/best-time-to-ask-questions-on-stackexchange-more-likely-to-get-an-answer), as the chances of a question that doesn't get closed *not* being answered are about as low as . . . well, something improbable.

Anyway, I switched the site to Worldbuilding Stack Exchange and the inputs to

- `All = 1` (all users)
- `Frequency = 1` (Gets data for the average day)
- `MaxTimeDiff = 1440` (Data ranges over the course of 1,440 minutes, i.e. one day)
- `UserID = 1` (all users; redundant since `All = 1`)

Here's the graph I got:

[image]

As you can see, the shortest answer time - the lowest point on the graph - is approximately 13:00 UTC. At this point:

- East Asia and Australia are in or entering the night.
- Africa, Europe, and the Middle East are at midday to afternoon - approaching teatime, in fact.
- South America is already well into the morning, possibly finishing off an early cup of coffee.
- North America is rubbing its eyes, getting out of bed, and possibly leaving the house.
- Antarctica is doing its own thing entirely.

This might give you a decent idea of the demographics of Worldbuilding users, interestingly enough.

The worst time to get an answer to a question is right around 0:00 UTC, which is, by a strange coincidence, right about now.

Comment: So, are you going to update the graph to take this answer into account?

Comment: "North America is rubbing its eyes, getting out of bed, and possibly leaving the house."  Really depends on where.  In Eastmost Canada, people would probably be at work (9:30 AM).  In New York City, leaving the house or arriving at work (8:00 AM).  In Los Angeles, many still sleep (5:00 AM).  And of course, add an hour for Daylight Savings Time at the moment.